# MySQL Join 1 to 1 in N items table

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I need some help on my shop database structure. To fetch items from category, there are already some joins, but i would like to add an image to an item, from other table. Main items table doesn't have an image id, so we just get one from other table by it's weight = 1.

So, there is a structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `category_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`        VARCHAR(255)
                CHARACTER SET utf8mb4     DEFAULT NULL
  COMMENT 'Category title',
  `parent_id`   INT(11)          NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  COMMENT 'Category Parent ID',
  `status`      TINYINT(1)                DEFAULT '0'
  COMMENT 'Category active status',
  `weight`      INT(11)                   DEFAULT '0',
  `slug`        VARCHAR(255)
                CHARACTER SET utf8mb4     DEFAULT NULL
  COMMENT 'Category url alias',
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `item_id`     INT(11) UNSIGNED           NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`        VARCHAR(255)
                CHARACTER SET utf8mb4      NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  COMMENT 'Item name',
  `description` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL
  COMMENT 'Item description',
  `user_id`     INT(11) UNSIGNED           NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  COMMENT 'User id',
  `category_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED           NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  COMMENT 'Category id',
  `price`       DECIMAL(10, 2)             NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
  COMMENT 'Item price',
  `status`      INT(1) UNSIGNED            NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
  COMMENT 'Item status',
  `deleted`     INT(1) UNSIGNED            NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  COMMENT 'Delite status',
  `blocked`     INT(1) UNSIGNED            NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  COMMENT 'Block status',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_images` (
  `id`      INT(11) UNSIGNED      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED      NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `file`    VARCHAR(255)
            CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `weight`  INT(11) UNSIGNED      NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status`  TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED   NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED   NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` INT(11) UNSIGNED      NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  ROW_FORMAT = COMPACT;
```

As you can see from there, category structure also contain `parent_id` inside, so we can always get the category tree.

Using this query is working as well and really fast.

```
SELECT
  `i`.*,
  `c1`.`name` AS `category_name`,
  `c1`.`slug` AS `category_slug`,
  `c2`.`name` AS `subcategory_name`,
  `c2`.`slug` AS `subcategory_slug`
FROM `items` AS `i`
  LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `c2` ON `c2`.`category_id` = `i`.`category_id`
  LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `c1` ON `c1`.`category_id` = `c2`.`parent_id`
WHERE `i`.`deleted` = 0 AND `i`.`blocked` = 0 AND `i`.`status` = 1
ORDER BY `i`.`created` DESC
LIMIT 40
```

But, if i join `items_images` like:

```
SELECT
  `i`.*,
  `ii`.`file` AS `image`,
  `c1`.`name` AS `category_name`,
  `c1`.`slug` AS `category_slug`,
  `c2`.`name` AS `subcategory_name`,
  `c2`.`slug` AS `subcategory_slug`
FROM `items` AS `i`
  LEFT JOIN `items_images` AS `ii`
    ON `i`.`item_id` = `ii`.`item_id` AND `ii`.`weight` = 1
   AND `ii`.`status` = 1 AND `ii`.`deleted` = 0
  LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `c2` ON `c2`.`category_id` = `i`.`category_id`
  LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `c1` ON `c1`.`category_id` = `c2`.`parent_id`
WHERE `i`.`deleted` = 0 AND `i`.`blocked` = 0 AND `i`.`status` = 1
 ORDER BY `i`.`created` DESC LIMIT 40
```

Sometimes it takes up to 1 minute on 14k items with 40k images.

Is there something i can improve?! Please note, there might be items without images too. That is not requirement.

Small addition. Even single images join on items makes the query run over a minute. here a sample:

```
SELECT `i`.*, `ii`.`file` AS `image` FROM `items` AS `i` 
LEFT JOIN `items_images` AS `ii` ON `i`.`item_id` = `ii`.`item_id`
         AND `ii`.`weight` = 1 AND `ii`.`status` = 1 AND `ii`.`deleted` = 0 
WHERE `i`.`deleted` =0 AND `i`.`sold` =0 AND `i`.`blocked` =0 AND `i`.`status` = 1 
ORDER BY `i`.`created` DESC
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept - not that that will help performance any. Can we see the EXPLAIN for the problem query?

Comment: @Strawberry i added order by and limit. still nothing.

Comment: As I said. Please provide the EXPLAIN

Comment: You may have a rule that every column have a 'comment', but this is ludicrous: `description ... COMMENT 'Item description'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have inconsistency in naming convention.
2. Index parent_id

   ALTER TABLE categories ADD INDEX parent_id_ind (parent_id ASC) ;
3. Try to run your query again.

In databases you would use indexes to improve the speed of data retrieval. An index is typically created on columns used in JOIN, WHERE, and ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Added index, still the same. Joining images takes too long.

Comment: How much time before and after index ?

Comment: Still over a minute... Even joining images in items is killing everything. Sample:

Comment: @GordonFreeman Index items_images.item_id also, ALTER TABLE items_images ADD INDEX item_id_ind (item_id ASC) ;

Comment: OP amended the question to add that in fact the problem still occurs without categories. Therefore, adding an index on categories can't possibly fix it. An index on `item_id` in `items_images`, on the other hand...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to improve your structure, you can take it or leave it,

Here my suggestion:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category`;
  CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category title',
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Category Parent ID',
  `status` enum('status1','status2') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category active status',
  `weight` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `slug` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category url alias',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category_id_ind` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `item`;
    CREATE TABLE `item` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Item name',
      `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL COMMENT 'Item description',
      `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User id',
      `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Category id',
      `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'Item price',
      `status` enum('status1','status2') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'status1' COMMENT 'Item status',
      `is_deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Delite status',
      `is_blocked` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Block status',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `item_images`;
    CREATE TABLE `item_images` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `file_path` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL ,
      `weight` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `is_deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: Renaming the columns brings no speed improvement.

Comment: @4EACH -- Please give a synopsis of the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

Add composite indexes:

```
items:  INDEX(deleted, blocked, status, created)  -- created must be last
items_images:  INDEX(item_id, weight, status, deleted)
categories:  INDEX(category_id, deleted, blocked, status)
```

Except as noted, the order of columns is not important.

Remove `LEFT` unless you see a need for it.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

The likely reason for the sluggishness is having to check lots of image rows for `weight=1`.  On top of that, the lack of any useful index means a costly table scan.